# Remove specific attribute from entire xml in Python

Tags: python, xml, xslt-1.0, elementtree

I need to remove all **id** attributes from XML using Python. It will be part of a bigger app and will be the input for some transformations after.

Example code:

```
<body>
    <r1 format="bold" id="NODE1">
        <r2 title="Test" id="NODE2">
            <r3 group="123" type="Operation" id="NODE3">
                <rtit id="NODE4">Evaluate the temperature</rtit>
                <procedure id="NODE5">
                    <procstep id="NODE6">
                        <graphelem id="NODE7">
                            <graphic graphicname="T123456" res_width="3.58in" scale="70" id="NODE8"/>
                        </graphelem>
                        <proct>Remove the screws. Remove the plates.</proct>
                    </procstep>
                    <procstep id="NODE9">
                        <graphelem id="NODE10">
                            <graphic graphicname="T654321" res_width="3.58in" scale="70" id="NODE11"/>
                        </graphelem>
                        <proct>Fix the thermocouple in the cover.</proct>
                    </procstep>
                </procedure>
            </r3>
        </r2>
    </r1>
</body>
```

The source files have more than 1000 lines, and more than 30 different XML tags that contain the **id** attribute.

The expected result is:

```
<body>
    <r1 format="bold">
        <r2 title="Test">
            <r3 group="123" type="Operation">
                <rtit>Evaluate the temperature</rtit>
                <procedure>
                    <procstep>
                        <graphelem>
                            <graphic graphicname="T2093978" res_width="3.58in" scale="70"/>
                        </graphelem>
                        <proct>Remove the screws. Remove the plates.</proct>
                    </procstep>
                    <procstep>
                        <graphelem>
                            <graphic graphicname="T654321" res_width="3.58in" scale="70"/>
                        </graphelem>
                        <proct>Fix the thermocouple in the cover.</proct>
                    </procstep>
                </procedure>
            </r3>
        </r2>
    </r1>
</body>
```

I've tried to use xslt to make the transformation except for the **id** attribute, but without any success.

Does anyone help me with this issue, please?

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: Sorry for the missing info. The XSLT that I use has more than a thousand lines and I believe that it would waste your time to read it. The elementtree approach would be better.

Comment: XSLT has a so called **Identity Transform** pattern. for your you case it is one line XSLT template that will do the job.

Comment: Thank you, Yitzhak. I will look for more information about this resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to remove all id attributes from XML using Python.

Something like the below - loop over all elements and drop the 'id' attrib

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<body><r1 format="bold" id="NODE1">
        <r2 title="Test" id="NODE2">
            <r3 group="123" type="Operation" id="NODE3">
                <rtit id="NODE4">Evaluate the temperature</rtit>
                <procedure id="NODE5">
                    <procstep id="NODE6">
                        <graphelem id="NODE7">
                            <graphic graphicname="T123456" res_width="3.58in" scale="70" id="NODE8"/>
                        </graphelem>
                        <proct>Remove the screws. Remove the plates.</proct>
                    </procstep>
                    <procstep id="NODE9">
                        <graphelem id="NODE10">
                            <graphic graphicname="T654321" res_width="3.58in" scale="70" id="NODE11"/>
                        </graphelem>
                        <proct>Fix the thermocouple in the cover.</proct>
                    </procstep>
                </procedure>
            </r3>
        </r2>
    </r1>
</body>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for elem in root.iter():
  if 'id' in elem.attrib:
    del elem.attrib['id']
ET.dump(root)
```

Comment: Great! It works fine. Thanks!